# Conectar Banco de dados com HTML

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

**Como conecto o meu banco de dados com html?**

CÓDIGO HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CADASTRO DE CLIENTES COM BANCO DE DADOS E PHP</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
color: #FF0000;
font-size: x-small;
}
.style3 {color:#7678ff; font-size: x-small; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validaCampo()
{
if(document.cadastro.nome.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo nome é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.email.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo email é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.endereco.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo endereço é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.cidade.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo Cidade é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.estado.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo Estado é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.bairro.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo Bairro é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.pais.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo país é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
else
if(document.cadastro.login.value=="")
{
alert("O Campo Login é obrigatório!");
return false;
}
var password = document.getElementById("password")
  , confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword(){
  if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Senhas diferentes!");
  } else {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;

else
if(document.cadastro.senha.value=="")
{
alert("Digite uma senha!");
return false;
}
else
return true;
}

<!-- Fim do JavaScript que validará os campos obrigatórios! -->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="cadastro.php" onsubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;">
  <table width="625" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="69">Nome:</td>
      <td width="546"><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="70" maxlength="60" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="70" maxlength="60" />
      <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>CPF:</td>
      <td><input name="cpf" type="text" id="cpf" size="70" maxlength="60" />
      <span class="style1">*</span></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RG:</td>
      <td><input name="rg" type="text" id="rg" size="70" maxlength="60" />
      <span class="style1">*</span></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sexo:</td>
      <td><input name="sexo" type="radio" value="Masculino" checked="checked" />
        Masculino
        <input name="sexo" type="radio" value="Feminino" />
        Feminino <span class="style1">*</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Telefone</td>
      <td>

        <input name="telefone" type="text" id="telefone" 
       size ="70" maxlength="60"/>
        <span class="style3">Apenas números</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Endereço:</td>
      <td><input name="endereco" type="text" id="endereco" size="70" maxlength="70" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cidade:</td>
      <td><input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Estado:</td>
      <td><select name="estado" id="estado">
        <option>Selecione...</option>
        <option value="AC">AC</option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
        <option value="AP">AP</option>
        <option value="AM">AM</option>
        <option value="BA">BA</option>
        <option value="CE">CE</option>
        <option value="ES">ES</option>
        <option value="DF">DF</option>
        <option value="MA">MA</option>
        <option value="MT">MT</option>
        <option value="MS">MS</option>
        <option value="MG">MG</option>
        <option value="PA">PA</option>
        <option value="PB">PB</option>
        <option value="PR">PR</option>
        <option value="PE">PE</option>
        <option value="PI">PI</option>
        <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
        <option value="RN">RN</option>
        <option value="RS">RS</option>
        <option value="RO">RO</option>
        <option value="RR">RR</option>
        <option value="SC">SC</option>
        <option value="SP">SP</option>
        <option value="SE">SE</option>
        <option value="TO">TO</option>
          </select>
        <span class="style1">*      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bairro:</td>
      <td><input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>País:</td>
      <td><input name="pais" type="text" id="pais" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Senha:</td>
      <td><input name="senha" type="password" id="senha" maxlength="12" />
          <span class="style1">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input name="news" type="checkbox" id="news" value="ATIVO" checked="checked" />
Desejo receber novidades e informações sobre o conteúdo deste site. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Concluir meu Cadastro!" />


          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar Campos preenchidos!" />


          <span class="style1">* Campos com * são obrigatórios!          </span></p>
      <p>  </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CÓDIGO PHP

```
<title>Cadastro realizado com sucesso!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
// RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !

$nome= $_POST ["nome"];//atribuição do campo "nome" vindo do formulário para variavel
$email= $_POST ["email"];//atribuição do campo "email" vindo do formulário para variavel
$cpf= $_POST ["cpf"];//atribuição do campo "cpf" vindo do formulário para variavel
$rg= $_POST ["rg"];//atribuição do campo "rg" vindo do formulário para variavel
$tel= $_POST ["telefone"];//atribuição do campo "telefone" vindo do formulário para variavel
$endereco= $_POST ["endereco"];//atribuição do campo "endereco" vindo do formulário para variavel
$cidade= $_POST ["cidade"];//atribuição do campo "cidade" vindo do formulário para variavel
$estado= $_POST ["estado"];//atribuição do campo "estado" vindo do formulário para variavel
$bairro = $_POST ["bairro"];//atribuição do campo "bairro" vindo do formulário para variavel
$pais= $_POST ["pais"];//atribuição do campo "pais" vindo do formulário para variavel
$senha= $_POST ["senha"];//atribuição do campo "senha" vindo do formulário para variavel
$news= $_POST ["news"];//atribuição do campo "news" vindo do formulário para variavel
$sexo= $_POST ["sexo"];//atribuição do campo "sexo" vindo do formulário para variavel

//Gravando no banco de dados ! conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root"); //localhost é onde esta o banco de dados.
if (!$conexao)
die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());

//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("clientes",$conexao); //nome da tabela que deseja que seja inserida os dados cadastrais
if (!$banco)
die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());


//Query que realiza a inserção dos dados no banco de dados na tabela indicada acima
$query = "INSERT INTO `clientes` ( `nome` , `email` ,`cpf`,`rg`,`sexo`,`telefone` , `endereço` , `cidade` , `estado` , `bairro` , `país` , `senha` , `news` , `id` ) 
VALUES ('$nome', '$email','$cpf','$rg','$sexo','$tel', '$endereco', '$cidade', '$estado', '$bairro', '$pais','$senha', '$news', '')";
mysql_query($query,$conexao);
########## • Explicação da query • ##########
#$query = nome da variavel que decidi#
#utilizar para realizar a operação.#
#############################################
#clientes = nome da tabela que será salvo#
#os dados do cadastro do cliente#
#############################################
#nome, email,cpf,rg, sexo, telefone,#
#endereço, cidade, estado, bairro, país,#
#senha, news, id.#
##
#São apenas os nomes dos campos que #
#constam na tabela clientes.#
#############################
#VALUES = indica que serão inseridos os#
#seguintes valores.#
#############################################
#$nome, $email,$cpf,$rg,$sexo,$telefone,#
#$endereço, $cidade, $estado, $bairro, #
#$país,$senha, $news, $id.#
#############################
#São apenas as variaveis a qual eu#
#atribui os valores digitados no formulá-#
#rio.#
#############################################
echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!Agradecemos a atenção.";
//mensagem que é escrita quando os dados são inseridos normalmente.
mysqli_close($conexao,$query);
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

CÓDIGO MYSQL

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
`nome` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`cpf` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`rg` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`telefone` VARCHAR( 60 ) ,
`endereço` VARCHAR( 70 ) NOT NULL ,
`cidade` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`estado` VARCHAR( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
`bairro` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`país` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`login` VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
`senha` VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
`news` VARCHAR( 8 ) ,
`id` INT( 200 ) AUTO_INCREMENT ,
UNIQUE (
`id` 
)
);
```

Erro Localhost

> Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line
>   10
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on
>   line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cpf in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line
>   12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: rg in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line
>   13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: sexo in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line
>   14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: telefone in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on
>   line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: endereco in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on
>   line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cidade in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on
>   line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined index: estado in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on
>   line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined index: bairro in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on
>   line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined index: pais in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line
>   20
>
> Notice: Undefined index: senha in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on
>   line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined index: news in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line
>   22
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct() expects at most 6 parameters, 13 given
>   in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 25
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php:26 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 26

Comment: Sugiro editar a pergunta, o `HTML` é uma linguagem para exibição de conteúdo no navegador e não conecta com banco de dados, no seu caso isso será feito no `php`. Estude o que faz o comando `$_POST` do php, veja que o seu html envia o formulário para a página "cadastro.php" e você está tentando ler os dados numa outra página "index.php"

Comment: Você pode apenas adicionar "required" após os inputs para dizer que é obrigatório, é mais simples. Você mantem apenas o script de verificar se a senha e a confirmação de senha são iguais.

Comment: As mensagens de erro não refletem o código postado na pergunta. Precisa [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código certo ou as mensagens corretas.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
O seu primeiro problema é no entendimento da arquitetura de uma aplicação Web.

No seu HTML você aponta o action do form para um arquivo *(action="cadastro.php")*, mas vendo os erros gerados observa-se que você está tentando processar o arquivo index.php.
Desta forma, tenta-se acesso a variáveis no cabeçalho ($_POST) que não existem.
Veja o erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line
>   10

**Basicamente: o índice nome é indefinido na linha 10 de index.php.**

Você deve processar o arquivo cadastro.php após o formulário da página HTML ter sido *submitado* (enviado).
Fazendo isso, estes erros vão sumir.

Outro problema é com a conexão com o BD.
Veja o erro apresentado:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct() expects at most 6 parameters, 13 given in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 25

Esta conexão está errada.
Recomendo usar PDO, por ser nativo:

```
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=clientes', 'root', 'senha'
);
```

Com isso você garante uma conexão com o Banco de Dados.
Ao usar PDO, melhor você mudar a forma de lidar com transações MySQL.
Use Prepared Statement:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
'INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (:title, :content)');
$title = 'Titulo do post';
$content = 'Conteudo do post';

$stmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindValue(':content', $content);
$stmt->execute();
```